# Node.js sockets.io need for synchronization?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, synchronization, thread-safety

I'm currently working with node.js, using the socket.io library, to implement a simple chat application. In this applicatio, for irrelevant reasons, I want to setup a system in which a client can ask for a piece of information to the server. The server then broadcasts this request to all other online sockets which will respond with the the answer if they have it. The server then finally returns (the first) response it receives to this original client socket that made the request.

Naturally, the client might receive multiple responses, while only one is needed. Therefor, as soon as one has been received, the others should be discarded. However, it feels like I should use some kind of synchronized datastructure/code to make sure this check for "If an answer has already been received" works as intended.

I've done some searching on this subject but I've seen several mentions of node.js using an event-driven model and not requiring any synchronized code/datastructures, as there are no multiple threads. Is this true? Would my scenario not require any kind of special attention to synchronization and would it just work? Or would I need to use some synchronization methods and if so, which ones?

**Code example:**

```
socket.on('new_response', async data => {
    await processResponse(data)
});
```

Due to the fact I am working with encryption I have to make use of async/await, which further complicates things. The `processResponse` function does a check whether a response has been received already, if not, it processes it, else, it ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something as simple as including a uniqueID in each broadcast to the clients asking if they have a piece of information.  The clients then include that same uniqueID in any response they send.

With that, your server can receive answers from the clients and just keep track of which uniqueID values it has already received an answer for and then, if an answer has already been received for that uniqueID, then it would just ignore the later clients that respond.

The uniqueID is server-side generated so it can literally just be an increasing number.  You can store the numbers used so far in a server-side Set object so you can quickly look up if you've already received a response for that uniqueID.

Then, the only thing left to do is to age these uniqueIDs away in the Set at some point so they don't accumulate forever.  A simple way to do that would be just replace the Set object with a second one every 15 minutes or so, keeping one older generation around so you can check both of them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This still raises the question though if that Set, or the piece of code which checks if a response has already been received, should be synchronized in any way. For example, in Scala one has to use [SynchronizedMap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/mutable/SynchronizedMap.html) and/or use the synchronized keyword around your if-test to make sure there are no data races. Is this applicable in this scenario as well?

Comment: @Arno - What do you mean "synchronized in some way"?  You haven't defined at all what that is or means.  Your question says this: ***"Therefor, as soon as one has been received, the others should be discarded."*** so that's what I advised you on how to make it work.  Because nodejs runs your JS in a single thread, there is no issue with multiple responses coming back from the client.  Those will be processed one at a time.

Comment: With that I mean taking care of concurrency. For example, if socket.io would process each incomming message with a seperate thread, and they share this one Set variable, then dataraces could occur. That is my main concern at the moment. But from your response I am concluding that node.js/socket.io will handle each incoming message sequentially? Completely removing any need to be concerned about concurrency, correct?

Comment: @Arno - Yes, it will handle each incoming request sequentially.  If you have any asynchronous code between the time you receive the incoming request and the time you use the shared `Set` object, then you could have timing issues with more than one request in flight at the same time, but you aren't doing something asynchronous (and waiting for the async operation to finish), then you will only have one incoming request being processed at a time.  To comment in any further detail, we would need to see that code.

Comment: @Arno - So, has this answered your question now?

Comment: I have added a code example in my initial thread. As you can see, I am forced to use async/await due to working with encryption. Thus, I think I will be required to use some synchronization, any suggestions?

Comment: @Arno - Perhaps you do have an issue because of the `await`.  That's not enough code to know what to suggest.  Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can advise more completely.  In general, the more of your relevant REAL, ACTUAL code you can show us, the better we can advise you on the best course of action and the better we can write REAL, ACTUAL code that will help you, rather than just describe things in general.